# Adding menuitem to existing Context Menu of an Android TextEdit input view

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-edittext, menuitem

I have a situation where I have to add a menuitem to TextEdit's existing (default) Context Menu (in a non-Activity)

Following is the snippet of code I am using to achieve this. However, this doesn't show me any context menu.

```
/// Constructor

    editText.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(Field1_Clicked);
    editText.setLongClickable(true);
    editText.setOnLongClickListener(Field_Clicked);
```

I am doing this in Constructor because this is not an Activity. So, I cannot just say "registerForContextMenu(textView)". If I am not in an Activity, I can't override onContextItemSelected(). How do I listen to which Menu Item is clicked in this case?

```
/// OnCreateContextMenuListener 

    View.OnCreateContextMenuListener Field1_Clicked = new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            Log.d("Test", "Creating context menu");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST + 1, Menu.NONE, "New option");
        }
    };
```

This is never being called. I do not see the log message in the LogCat.

```
/// OnLongClickListener 

    OnLongClickListener Field_Clicked = new OnLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {            
            showContextMenu();
            return true;
        }   
    };

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getTitle().equals("New option")) {
         // Do something();
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Help of any sort would be appreciated. Thanks!